# Find and Close all Application Instances using win32api in Python

Tags: python, winapi, win32gui

I want to find and close all hidden Excel instances.

I would think the following code should:

1. Find an open instance of Excel
2. Terminate it

But it doesn't. Instead I get an error that the handle is invalid.

```
import win32api
import win32gui

excel_handle = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, None, "Excel")
win32api.TerminateProcess(excel_handle, 0)
```

How can I get a handle on an instance (or all instances) of Excel that are open? They may or may not be visible.

Comment: `FindWindowEx` return HWND. not handle to process. you need first call `GetWindowThreadProcessId(excel_handle, &dwProcessId)`, than `OpenProcess` for this `dwProcessId` and only finally `TerminateProcess` and `CloseHandle()`

Comment: `They may or may not be visible.` you faster need enumerate all processes in system via Process32First / Process32Next  on NtQuerySystemInformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it be acceptable to use [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/f", "/im", "EXCEL.EXE"])
```