# Issue when running win32com on Window 11

Tags: python, win32com

I'm now running Python on Window 11 to read Excel File protected with password. the python Script is as below

```
 import win32com.client
 file_path = '<my_file_path>'
 xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
 xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.qOpen(file_path, False, True, None, password)
```

and the Error is

```
  File "S:\GitHub\ncpt_database\main_src\src_code\readManualData.py", line 29, in readingEncryptedExcel
    xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file_path, False, True, None, password)
  File "C:\Users\sonnm6\.conda\envs\bidv\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 639, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("%s.%s" % (self._username_, attr))
AttributeError: Excel.Application.Workbooks
```

I don't know how to solve this problem. I have tried to remove the package and reinstall but it still reproduce the Error.

This Error on the version:

```
Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pywin32                   305              py39h2bbff1b_0    anaconda
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0           py39haa95532_1000
```

Pls help!

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for this problem, the `AttributeError` is normally occured because Excell process is still running, it might be hidden.

So we just need to close it manually in Task Manager or add this 2 lines of python script for killing Excel process automatically (the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44787526/find-and-close-all-application-instances-using-win32api-in-python))

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["taskkill", "/f", "/im", "EXCEL.EXE"])
```